# Who provides oversight of the politics.stackexchange.com site?

Tags: discussion, support, stackexchange

I have noticed a trend on [Politics.SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com) that questions and comments that reflect negatively on Trump are mysteriously disappearing.

- [Are there areas of London the police are afraid to enter?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/are-there-areas-of-london-the-police-are-afraid-to-enter) (showed as closed as Opinion Based on Android, appears to have been re-opened)
- [What exactly did Donald Trump say about abortion?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/10436/what-exactly-did-donald-trump-say-about-abortion) (comments all migrated to chat, removing the challenge that what the quotes the answer describes as a clarification is a reversal of position)
- (another example I can no longer find, which included a comment linking to a contextually relevant example of a government revoking citizenship)

Who provides oversight for that site to ensure it isn't abused to support one political persuasion over another?

Comment: Comments are supposed to be "temporary "Post-It" notes left on a question or answer." If someone is using a comment to say "$candidate is great!" or "I hate $candidate"... that's a misuse of the comment feature.

Comment: Right, but when it's to show an answer is misleading, it shouldn't get scrubbed.

Answer (score 2):

When a comment thread gets gets about 20 replies long, I move the comments to chat, and I ultimately purge the entire comments section.

Occasionally, I'll leave the first few comments if they're obviously on topic, but comments like the following don't cut it.

> The less attention paid to Donald Trump, the better. He has no more chance of being president than you do.
>
> Clarified or backpedalled?

If you don't want your comments deleted, then don't get into arguments in the comments section. If you feel like you're having a debate with someone rather than making a meaningful comment on the answer/question, then try to refrain from posting it.

---

As for your other question, There are 2 moderators here, and users are able to vote on closing/opening questions.  If you have an issue with how a post was moderated, go ahead and flag it.  And we'll usually allow the other moderator to handle that flag.

If you're not satisfied with that, you can click the "Contact Us" link at the bottom, and contact the SE staff.

See the following post for more details:  [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused his/her privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges/28869#28869)

Comment: Those two comments are unrelated and from separate authors. If you refer to the answer, you can see that 'clarified' is used incorrectly to describe a change of stated opinion - the answer was being challenged on the grounds of the author's bias and misrepresentation of the cited evidence.

Comment: @PhilLello I don't see what the issue here is. The comments section is not a mini chat room, it really isn't build to support long back & forth conversations. The "Clarified or backpedalled?" comment may not look that bad on its own, but it did spark a 15 comments long and mostly pointless conversation. Moving the comments to chat was more than appropriate and a far cry from your rather unfair claim that "comments that reflect negatively on Trump are mysteriously disappearing".